# Docker maven plugin NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, docker, microservices

I have a multi-module maven java project and I want each module to create a docker container during build phase. I have used the following sample project with microservices as a base project: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example

Plugin configuration is as follows:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This works ok in the base project and all containers are built correctly. When I updated the *groupId* and *artifactId* in the parent and all child modules with my own, then I get the following error during build of child modules

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default) on project users-microservice: Exception caught: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default) on project users-microservice: Exception caught
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:141)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute(BuildMojo.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.<init>(DefaultDockerClient.java:298)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.<init>(DefaultDockerClient.java:290)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$Builder.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1840)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.buildDockerClient(AbstractDockerMojo.java:169)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:138)
```

If I switch the child modules to consider as parent not my own *groupId*/*artifactId* but the ones used in the example, then everything works ok. Am I missing something? Should I upload my parent module somewhere or declare a registry?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Maven, multi module projects have to get their groupId from their parent.

Comment: I updated the parent pom as well. To make it more clear, the example project has parent pom A and all children modules declare A as their parent. So what I did is simply replace A with B, so that in my project all children modules have B as their parent, but this does not work. It seems like docker maven plugin searches for the declared parent in some kind of repository.

Comment: The groupId should not be specified in the children/modules.  I also think the same applied to the version.  They should come from the parent.